# How to prevent accidentally dragging vertex on selection?

Tags: vertices, select

When manually selecting a single vertex in Edit mode, I sometimes hold the mouse button down for a split second longer and end up dragging the vertex just a tiny bit. Most times I wont notice it.

This becomes a problem when faces are no longer flat.

Is there a method by which to avoid this? Perhaps a new key binding requiring a key press and mouse down to move a vertex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set mouse or tablet drag distance to a higher value like 50px so that the drag operation will not start so easily:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly, thanx Martynas.

Answer (score 3):

*I know this has already been answered and I've used the [solution by Martynas](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203295/31447) for a long time myself.*

However, I've recently found a better way: You can modify the keymap to eliminate the "move" functionality entirely. Search for the Name "Move" in the keymap and deselect this setting:

[image: Screenshot]

But keep it active for moving with <kbd>G</kbd>. You can do the same in the *Graph Editor*. I don't think this should interfere with LCS or using the tweak gizmos. Please comment if you run into issues with any of those.

This method lets you keep lower drag thresholds which makes the overall feeling a lot snappier.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are using the select mode "tweak" which has that behavior that you are describing, where you can click and drag the mesh, but you really want something that is more akin to the "box select" where you are just selecting, and not moving. You can click individual vertices in box select mode as well. The top left of the 3d viewport shows your select mode, and W cycles through them.

"tweak" select mode
[image: tweak mode]

"box" select mode
[image: box select mode]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#tool-select-box

Comment: sorry, can't seem to attach a screen shot, tho using "box select" with "vertex select" and mode is "set a new selection" ... operating system is linux tho that shouldn't make too much of a difference. using the old style profile, ie right mouse button for select. PS ... only a single vertex is dragged if the mouse button is held a fraction too long